# Can't install kext, "Read-only file system"

Tags: macos, audio, permissions, kernel-extension

So, I've been racking my brain against the wall for the last 6 hours trying to get this to work and I'm still at a loss..

I'm trying to install a kext on Big Sur from this repo, https://github.com/SimulPiscator/vpcm, and when I try and move the compiled kext to `/System/Library/Extensions` I keep getting 'Read-only file system' error..

- I have disabled SIP
- Tried enabling root user
- Added myself to the 'wheel' group
- Reduced security level in security utility
- Tried changing permissions on the `/System` dir, keeps telling me I don't have permission.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious... Every article I've seen online tells me to put the kext in that directory and run kextload.. But how the heck do I get write permissions to that directory??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I'm not sure if this is what is supposed to happen or not, but placing the kext in `/Library/Extensions` instead of `/System/Library/Extensions` worked.

I'm not sure if this is the correct thing to do but since it works, I'm not complaining.

Comment: Yes, `/Library/Extensions/` has been the correct location for third-party kernel extensions since OS X 10.9. Only on Mountain Lion and older should you install to `/System/Library/Extensions/`.